# How can i fix the following gmp library dependency error while trying to install Charm?

Tags: python, unix, gmp, charm-crypto

I am trying to install the `Charm` crypto python framework in Ubuntu 11.04 with python 2.7.

The requirements say that I should have `gmp` version 5.* installed. I have successfully installed the `gmp` library and run all the tests.

Also, after running

```
$ ldconfig -p |grep libgmp
libgmpxx.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so.4
libgmpxx.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so
libgmp.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10
libgmp.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3
libgmp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so
libgmp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgmp.so
```

In order to install `Charm`,  I have downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/releases/download/v0.43/Charm-Crypto-0.43_Python3.tar.gz). I run `./configure, make , make install`, and `sdconfig` as the INSTALL says.

But after running `make test` I am getting a lot of errors of this form:

```
charm/Charm-Crypto-0.43/charm/core/math/integer.so: undefined symbol: __gmpz_powm_sec
```

**`Charm` shared libraries cannot find `libgmp`. How can i fix that?**

I did an `ldd integer.so` and it uses `libgmp.so.3`. In my system `libgmp.so.3` is placed under `/usr/lib` so added this line under the `config.mk` file of the `Charm` framework:

```
LDFLAGS= -m64 -L/usr/lib .
```

(`-m64` was already there). I `make` and `make install` again but I am getting the same error

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/


Comment: It does find libgmp, or the error message would be different. Use `ldd` to check which version of GMP it linked to. If it mentions `libgmp.so.3`, try adding `-L/usr/local/lib` to LDFLAGS.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes it mentions libgmp.so.3. But where should i put LDFLAGS var?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I added this `LDFLAGS=-m64 -L/usr/local/lib` 
 to my config.mk file which is included in the Makefile of the Charm framework and i rebuilt it but i am getting the same error. (-m64 was already there)

Comment: Actually under /usr/local/lib there is not libgmp.so.3 but only these:`libgmp.so libgmp.so.10 libgmp.so.10.0.2 libgmp.so.10.0.5`